# What does this certain piece do in this snippet of TCL code

Tags: scripting, tcl, tk-toolkit

I`m curious as to what this "2>@ stderr <@ stdin" does in this snippet of code in TCL:

```
if {[catch {eval exec $listCmds 2>@ stderr <@ stdin } cmdList] } { …
```

Based on what I know, `catch` runs the command in the inner curly braces `{}` and it stores the output in `cmdList`. If it was successful, it doesn't enter the `if` statement, and if not then it does. PS: I'm coming from a C++ background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`eval exec $listCmds` runs a separate program with name and arguments taken from the variable listCmds. (Actually a more modern and safer idiom for this would be `exec {*}$listCmds`).

`2>@ stderr` redirects standard error output from this program to the standard error channel of the Tcl script, see https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.htm#M20 .

`<@ stdin` redirects the standard input of this program from the standard input channel of the Tcl script, see https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.htm#M11 .

Comment: Added a community wiki followup to your answer. Feel free to add or edit.

Answer (score 2):

And the missing piece to [Colin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53079218/7552) is the mix of catch/exec/redirect stderr: **only** the spawned process's **stdout** will be captured in `cmdList`.

- if you do not redirect the process's stderr to Tcl's stderr, then exec considers any stderr output from the process to be an error:

  ```
  $ echo '
      set rc [catch {exec sh -c {echo to stdout; echo to stderr >&2}} result]
      puts "rc=$rc result=>$result<"
  ' | tclsh
  rc=1 result=>to stdout
  to stderr<
  ```
- when stderr is redirected, exec now doesn't know about the process's stderr, and the catch resultVar will not capture it

  ```
  $ echo '
      set rc [catch {exec sh -c {echo to stdout; echo to stderr >&2} 2>@stderr} result]
      puts "rc=$rc result=>$result<"
  ' | tclsh
  to stderr
  rc=0 result=>to stdout<
  ```

  Note how the "to stderr" shows up by itself. We can now redirect it like any other stderr output:

  ```
  $ echo '
      set rc [catch {exec sh -c {echo to stdout; echo to stderr >&2} 2>@stderr} result]
      puts "rc=$rc result=>$result<"
  ' | tclsh 2>/dev/null
  rc=0 result=>to stdout<
  ```